# static template variable in template class

Tags: c++, templates, template-variables

I want to define the static template variable of a templated class. But I can't get the correct syntax here:

```
template < typename T>
class X
{
    public:
        T i;
        X(T _i): i{_i}{}

        operator T(){ return i; }
}; 

 template < typename T2 >
 class Y
 {
     public:
         template <typename T>
             static X<T> x_in_y;
 };

 // something like that, which currently do not compile     
 template< typename T2, typename T>
 X<T> Y<T2>::x_in_y<T>{9.9};

 int main()
 {
      std::cout << Y<int>::x_in_y<float> << std::endl;
 }
```

Comment: Don't use static template variable member of template class with clang! https://godbolt.org/z/dCZq7I That makes Clang crash, or worst!

Comment: @Oliv: Ubs! Thanks for the hint. That seems that both compilers are buggy here!

Comment: No that is only a Clang bug , gcc does not have this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x_in_y` is a template in a template so you need a nested template declaration:

```
template<typename T2>
template<typename T>
X<T> Y<T2>::x_in_y{9.9};
```

Comment: g++ complains about "X<T> Y<T2>::x_in_y<T>{9.9};" but "X<T> Y<T2>::x_in_y{9.9};" works?!

Comment: You don't define a variable by saying int foo<int>;   but that's essentially what your first syntax tries to do.

Comment: @Klaus Get rid of the rightmost `<T>`. I mistakenly had that in my answer too.

Comment: Yep, already done ;) Can you tell in addition something about the partial specialization? I added some use cases to my question. Thanks!

Comment: @Klaus You should put that as a separate question.

Comment: @0x499602D2: Done! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53687873/partial-specilization-of-static-template-var-in-template-class